# Best approach for a date validation in object oriented design

Tags: java, date, object

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to validate a date. I am constructing this date by using objects.

```
public Appointment(String description , AppointmentDate appointmentDate)
{
    this.description = description; 
    this.appointmentDate = appointmentDate;
}
```

This is just a simple constructor which is using the information from appointmentDate to create an appointment.

```
public AppointmentDate(Date startTime,Date endTime,Date appDate){
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.appDate = appDate; 

}
```

This is then the appointmentDate constructor which is passed in the parameter of the appointment constructor.

I am leaning towards the isLenient() method to check if the user input is a valid date but I'm curious that there could be an easier way of doing this

```
public void add(Appointment a) 
{
    try
    {
        a.setLenient(false);
        appointmentCalender.add(a);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Date");
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using `java.util.Date` or (better) `java.time.LocalDate`, the values should already be valid.  A better solution is to make sure that the input is valid before it gets to `Appointment`, how that gets done is a broad question based on "how" you're getting the input

Comment: I'm using a scanner to acquire the input of the user. Then I'm splitting the string input and placing them in different indexes of an array while formatting them correctly.

Comment: The I would use a DateTimeFormatter to parse the input string against the required format to test that the input is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this, It is my logic but you can get an idea from this

```
public void add(Appointment a) 
{
    if (dateValidate(a)){
        appointmentCalender.add(a);
    }else{
    System.out.println("Invalid Date");
    }
}

public boolean dateValidate(Appointment a){

    if(a.getAppointmentDate().getStartTime().after(a.getAppointmentDate().getAppDate())){
        if(a.getAppointmentDate().getEndTime().after(a.getAppointmentDate().getStartTime())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```